# change bar chart column color in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I have the task of changing colors in graph -> bar chart columns.
By default they are blue.  But I want to change it. What should I do?
Customize *odoo/addons/web/static/src/views/graph/graph_renderer.js* ?
I should write down a custom widget(owl component)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph colors are set in the [graph renderer](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/views/graph/graph_renderer.js#L42). For example for the bar chart, odoo get the color from [colors.js](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/views/graph/colors.js#L3) using the loop [index of the dataset](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/29a2402153dc95414dad8c833487e7dd18c8a222/addons/web/static/src/views/graph/graph_renderer.js#L210).

In the following example, we define a new graph view with custom renderer:

***graph_renderer.js***

```
/** @odoo-module **/

import { GraphRenderer } from "@web/views/graph/graph_renderer";


export class CustomGraphRenderer extends GraphRenderer {
    
}
```

***graph_view.js***

```
/** @odoo-module **/

import { GraphView } from "@web/views/graph/graph_view";
import { CustomGraphRenderer } from "./graph_renderer";
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";


class CustomGraphView extends GraphView {}
CustomGraphView.components.Renderer = CustomGraphRenderer;

registry.category("views").add("custom_graph", CustomGraphView);
```

You need to add the above files to the `assets` entry under         `web.assets_backend`

To use the new graph view, use the `js_class` attribute
of the graph view:

```
<graph js_class="custom_graph">
```

Comment: Thank you @Kenly very much you help me with an answer. I did not respond because not finishing it. But now I clarify how to change colors in the Bar chart.
I overide `export class CustomGraphRenderer extends GraphRenderer {
    getBarChartData() {...  dataset.backgroundColor = [<list of collors >]}`
and it works fine.
I found out that odoo use Chart.js module. And looking documentation about it.